# Combinatorics: choose a team of $k$ students so at least one class has multiple team members

Tags: combinatorics

An elementary school has $n$ classes with $20$ students each. In how many ways can the school choose a team of $k$ students in such a way that at least one class has multiple team members?

Comment: Hey welcome to MSE. It's important to provide as much context as possible and to show what work you've already done on the problem, or at least the way you are thinking of approaching it.

Answer (score 2):

By your own logic, you can use:

$$\text{(total number of orderings) - (number when 0 classes have multiple team members)}$$

The total is:

$${20n \choose k}$$

To find the number which can be formed with only a maximum of *one* student per class, you first choose k classes:

$${n \choose k}$$

Then, pick a single student in each of those classes. There are $k$ decisions to be made here, and 20 options for each, so the total number of ways to choose the students is:

$$20^k$$

For a total of:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{valid teams} &= \text{total teams} - \text{invalid teams}\\
&= {20n \choose k} - {n \choose k}20^k
\end{align*}$$

Just in case you are unfamiliar with my notation here:

$${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{n!(n-k)!} = \text{The number of ways to choose k items from among n options}$$